# Xcode Source Extension in Xcode 14.3.1 problem

Tags: swift, xcode, simulator, macos-ventura, xcode14.3

I'm having trouble testing my Xcode Source Extension in Xcode 14.3.1. When I run it in the Xcode simulator, the extension doesn't show up in the editor. Is this issue specific to me, or has anyone else experienced it?

I also tried resetting my Xcode to see if that would resolve the issue.
Additionally, I attempted to find the location where I can enable my extension, but unfortunately, I couldn't locate it.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you go into System Settings > Extensions and enable it there?

Comment: @shim I tried looking into System Settings  Extensions as you mentioned, but I couldn't locate it.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 14.3.1 and earlier versions, Xcode Source Extensions are not available in the simulator. They can only be tested on a physical device.

Comment: How to test it in the physical device,this  extension is for Xcode